# using opencv to process an image in python

Tags: python, function, opencv

I am using OpenCV to try and process an image for my python class.

to load the image we are asked to retrieve a fully qualified path from the user and then also check if the path is valid. If the path is invalid I need to print a warning message and then terminate the function using return None. If the path is valid I want to print a success message and then return the value of the variable that I read the image into.

here is the code I have so far:
    import cv2
    import os

```
img_path = input("Enter a fully qualified path for an image: ")
#define a function to load an image
def img_loader():
     try:
        img = cv2.imread(img_path)
        #exists = os.path.isfile(img_path) #I used this in my if/else statement
        print("Success! The image path exists")
        return ReturnValue(img)
    except Exception:
        print("WARNING: The file path you entered was incorrect.")
        return None
```

when I run this script it gets the user input and then returns nothing at all (even when I commented out the 'return None' command)

I know that the path I'm using is correct but I'm not sure if I'm using the cv2.imread command correctly.

I've tried using both if/else and try/except for checking the path but I got the same result with both

How can I get my script to read the image into a variable and then return its value to the screen. Note: my teacher said that the value returned should be some sort of list

Comment: You need to actually **call** the function after defining it.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for the help, I was finally able to get it to work with this code.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import os

image_path = input("Enter a fully qualified path for an image: ")
#define a function to load an image
def img_loader(img_path):
    exists = os.path.isfile(img_path)
    if exists:
        img = cv2.imread(img_path)
        print("Success! The image path exists")
        return img
    else:
        print("WARNING: The file path you entered was incorrect.")
        return None

load=img_loader(image_path)   
print(load)
```